# List printer's completed jobs

Tags: printing, cups

Is there a utility to inspect the jobs that a printer has completed?

Comment: I added the [cups] tag and removed [command-line] since the accepted answer uses cups' web interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With CUPS (the standard printing system on Mac OS X, also used by many but not all other unices):

```
lpstat -W completed
```

Answer (score 2):

CUPS provides a list of all jobs on a printer on its web front-end.  Go to http://localhost:631/jobs?which_jobs=completed  or whatever machine is hosting the print server.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which printing system you are using. 
When using CUPS you would like to have a look at the page logifile, which shows you every page that has been printed. 
The default location of that file is: **/var/log/cups/page_log**